# django: request.POST is empty

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have the following rest API endpoint:

```
def post(request, *args, **kwargs):
   print(request.POST)
   short_description = request.POST.get("short_description", "")
   long_description = request.POST.get("long_description", "")

   # rest of the code goes here
```

when I call

```
response = client.post("/foo/bar/api/v1/error/1", {"short_description": "hello", "long_description": "world", format='json')
```

it gives me

`<QueryDict: {}>`

so both `short_description` and `long_description` is empty strings. How can I get that to pass the correct parameters in the POST?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `post` method in Django will store data in `request.body`, please check it

Comment: That was not the case...  "You cannot read from body after reading from request's data access"

Comment: You get an empty string because `request.POST` does not include 2 fields I think.